# SQL query to get correct data

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get TABLE2 data from TABLE1 data.

If `flg` is `1`, `cusId1` and `cusId2` are same person.

For example,
If `1` & `2` are same person and `2` & `3` are same person,
`1` & `3` are same person.

### TABLE1

| cusId1 | cusId2 | flg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 7 | 1 |
| 7 | 8 | 1 |
| 8 | 6 | 1 |

### TABLE2

| cusId | mainId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 8 | 6 |

I've been thinking about what kind of SQL to use, but I can't think of it.
Should I use recursive SQL?
The database type is Oracle12c.

```sql
WITH VREC (TABLE1 , cusId1  , cusId2) AS
(
   SELECT cusId1 || ' -> '|| cusId2 , cusId1, cusId2 FROM TABLE1
   WHERE cusId1 = '1' AND cusId2 = '2'
UNION ALL
   SELECT V.TABLE1 || ' -> '|| K.cusId2 , K.cusId1, K.cusId2 FROM TABLE1 K , VREC V
   WHERE V.cusId1 = K.cusId1
   AND flg = '1'
)
SELECT TABLE1 FROM VREC

# TABLE1
# 1 -> 1
# 1 -> 2 -> 3
```

Please let me know if you have a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather tricky because you a have a cyclic graph.  You can handle it using a recursive CTE and keeping track of the nodes that have been visited:

```
with alledges as (
      select cusid1, cusid2
      from t
      where flg = 1
      union all
      select cusid2, cusid1
      from t
      where flg = 1
      union all
      (select cusid1, cusid1
       from t
       where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.flg = 1 and t.cusid1 in (t2.cusid1, t2.cusid2))
       union
       select cusid2, cusid2
       from t
       where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.flg = 1 and t.cusid2 in (t2.cusid1, t2.cusid2))
      )
     ),
     cte (parentid, childid, visited) as (
      select distinct cusid1, cusid1, ',' || cusid1 || ','
      from alledges
      union all
      select cte.parentid, ae.cusid2, cte.visited || ae.cusid2 || ','
      from cte join
           alledges ae
           on cte.childid = ae.cusid1
      where cte.visited not like '%,' || ae.cusid2 || ',%'
     )
select childid, min(parentid) 
from cte
group by childid
order by childid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e680325095d135363d1a76024889f301) is a db<>fiddle.